# Jenkins maven target war

Tags: maven, jenkins

on my laptop i'm using maven-war-plugin to build me a war file that I later deploy to tomcat

now i'm trying to recreate this build process with Jenkins and the problem that when i set a maven target as war it returns an error msg

> [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "war".

how can I use war plugin on jenkins build process ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you don't call the war plugin directly, but you call `mvn clean install` on a project with packaging war. This will trigger all necessary steps, including compilation and also the war plugin.

So put in `clean install` in your Jenkins and this should be fine.